# jQuery Ajax call, why two requests listed in network activity?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am sending Ajax calls with a beforeSend header option ( adding Authorization token) , which runs fine, but I can see 2 requests listed in the console ...

```
    $.ajax('https://macMini.local:8000/Products', {
          type: "GET",
         cache: false,
         async: false,
         dataType: "json",
         beforeSend: function (xhr, settings){ 
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + amplify.store( "tokens" ).access_token); 
          }
     })...
```

and in the dev browser console, I see :

```
 Request URL:https://macmini.local:8000/Products?_=1381768498131
 Request Method:OPTIONS
 Status Code:204 No Content
 ...
```

with no response
and

```
 Request URL:https://macmini.local:8000/Products?_=1381768498131
 Request Method:GET
 Status Code:200 OK
 ...
```

with the JSON response

Comment: `async: false` === FAIL!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the ajax request made from another domain or port? In that case it's a [Cross-site HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), and the browser will first send a `OPTIONS` request to check if the GET-request is safe to send.

Normally a `GET` request wouldn't send `OPTIONS` first, but in this case the "[preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)" request is probably made because you set extra headers.

Comment: that's the case , I'm running both client and server ( node.js w CORS) in dev mode ...  thanks for clarifying this ...